# can we use "trip over the floor" to express "you fall because your flip flops, sandals, etc have too much friction on the floor"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Ok, this is the symptom that people who wear flip flops or sandals have.

That is **flip flops or sandals have too much friction on the floor**.

So when a person in flip flops etc walks, they may fall or nearly fall because the flip flops have strong friction on the floor & may cause a force that stops that person moving forward, but since the person is walking so he has a momentum of moving forward.

These 2 opposite forces may make him fall down.

> **[trip](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/trip_2)** [intransitive] to catch your foot on something and fall or almost fall
>
> *She tripped and fell.*
>
> **trip over/on something** *Someone will trip over that cable.*
>
> (figurative) I was tripping over my words in my excitement to tell
>   them the news.
>
> **trip over/up** *Be careful you don't trip up on the step.*

So, may I say?

*My toddler tripped over the floor in her sandals*

People often trip over a cable or a step, I am not sure if people **do trip over the floor**?

We may say "**trip on the floor**" but that may cause confusing because people may think "**trip over a cable on the floor**"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question!

I don't think "tripping over the floor" fits what you are trying to describe. When we trip *over* something, the 'something' is an object that caused us to stumble. *Tripping over the floor* would imply that perhaps some of the flooring is loose and has caused an obstruction.

In British English (possibly American too?) we have an idiomatic expression "*[tripping over your own feet](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/trip_over_one%27s_own_two_feet)*", which means to stumble while walking, without having tripped over anything.

This expression seems more appropriate to what you are describing, as no object is causing the stumbling - the footwear is just making it difficult for the wearer to lift their feet.

As an aside, some cases of "tripping over one's feet" are examples of the medical condition *foot drop*, in which a muscular weakness makes lifting the feet difficult.